# Remove nation flags at the bottom of tradingview

Tags: javascript, trading, tradingview-api

i don't know how to remove these icons at the bottom of trading view.

Here is my current trading view setup

```js
        new window.TradingView.widget({
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          symbol: "Binance:BTCUSDT",
          interval: "D",
          timezone: "Etc/UTC",
          theme: "dark",
          style: "1",
          locale: "en",
          disabled_features: ["create_volume_indicator_by_default"],
          toolbar_bg: "#121217",
          enable_publishing: false,
          allow_symbol_change: true,
          container_id: "tradingview_1327e",
          hide_legend: true
        })
```

[image]

Comment: Try to use `visibility: hidden` css to flag div.